# Not able to deploy Angular app made in Yeoman

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman

I created an app using Yeoman. It works fine on my local while "yeoman server" is running.

But when I created a dist, running "yeoman build", it doesn't work.
Here is link to the code on github: https://github.com/srijanaravali/yaspa

Node is running on my machine and demo project in angular seed works fine at the same time.

Comment: I misunderstood your issue. I thought it was related to code not running in the browser, not the actual 'yeoman build' step. I haven't tried porting to a newer yeoman, good luck.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?